# ng5-slider: Dragging pointers not moving when used in a Angular reactive form

Tags: angular

When I use the slider in a reactive form with a component that has `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` the slider pointers do not move even though the numbers do update.

This is my code for the component:

```
import { Component, AfterContentChecked, ChangeDetectorRef, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { Options } from 'ng5-slider';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.scss' ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent  {

  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    sliderControl: new FormControl([20, 80])
  });

  options: Options = {
    floor: 0,
    ceil: 100,
    showOuterSelectionBars: true
  }

  minValue = 20;
  maxValue = 80;
}
```

```
<div class="custom-slider" [formGroup]="form">
  <ng5-slider 
    formControlName="sliderControl"
    [options]="options" 
  >
  </ng5-slider>
</div>


<div class="custom-slider">
    <ng5-slider [(value)]="minValue" [(highValue)]="maxValue" [options]="options"></ng5-slider>
</div>
```

As you can see I have also tried with a template form as well where the slider does update.  You can see the full example here on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng5-slider-static-pointers)

Answer (score 0):

what i do is wrapping ng5-slider inside component

```
export class ControlWrapper implements ControlValueAccessor {

  public writeValue(obj: any) {
  }

  public registerOnChange(fn: any) {
  }

  public registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
  }

  public setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean) {
  }

}
```

my-slider.html

```
<ng5-slider
  [options]="options"
  [formControl]="ngControl.control"
  (ngModelChange)="onChange()"
></ng5-slider>
```

my-slider.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-slider',
  templateUrl: './my-slider.html'
})
export class MySlider extends ControlWrapper {

  public options: Options = {
    animate: false,
    step: 1
  };

  @Input()
  public set min(v: number) {
    this.options = {
      ...this.options,
      floor: v
    };
  }

  @Input()
  public set max(v: number) {
    this.options = {
      ...this.options,
      ceil: v
    };
  }

  constructor(
    @Optional()
    @Self()
    public ngControl: NgControl,
    private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    super();
    this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
  }

  public onChange() {
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't think this fixes the problem.  I did wrap the slider in a similar way but my slider is used deep down in a hierarchy of components all with onPush specified which prevents the slider handles from updating when used in a reactive form.

Comment: I also added the detectChanges code.  Whilst this does allow the slider handles to move, the movement is jerky and clicking on the slider bar does not move the handles correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Change detection is not done in the ng5-slider component, you can force it with `ChangeDetectorRef`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.scss' ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    sliderControl: new FormControl([20, 80])
  });

  options: Options = {
    floor: 0,
    ceil: 100,
    showOuterSelectionBars: true
  }

  minValue = 20;
  maxValue = 80;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form.get('sliderControl').valueChanges
      .subscribe(() => this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck())
  }
}
```